# Converting VB to Python for Labeling in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, labeling, python-parser, vb

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.1.

I am really new to Python and do not understand VB. I need to convert this VB script to Python.

The code is below. It believe it is looking for a numerical value within the field's attribute and then using that as the Interstate/Highway shield.

```vb
Function FindLabel ( [STREETNAME] )
' Extracts number from [STREETNAME]
' ---------------------------

  Dim sIn, sNew, i
  sIn = [STREETNAME]  ' input field value
  sNew = ""  'result
  i = 1

  ' check if char is numeric
  While i <= Len(sIn)    
    If IsNumeric(Mid(sIn, i, 1)) Then
      sNew = sNew & (Mid(sIn, i, 1))
    End If
    i = i + 1
  Wend
  FindLabel = sNew
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python lacks the isNumeric condition for the string. The best I could find is to use try/except on the int of the value (the crash 'n burn approach):

```
def FindLabel ( [STREETNAME] ):
    nVal = "" # set to an empty string just in case there's no numbers
    for part in [STREETNAME].split(): # breaks the string down to words and then steps over them as a variable called 'part'
        try:
            nVal = int(part) # convert this part of the string to an integer
            break # exit as soon as the first number is found
        except:
            pass # do nothing, we're expecting this failure
    return nVal
```

This function will return the first number in the string or an empty string if no numbers are found. It operates in essentially the same way as the VB script provided: iterates through the elements in the string until it finds a number and then returns that.

Comment: I asked a related question on StackOverflow three years ago and got a similar try/except answer (which validates yours) - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7682813/820534

Comment: This is the Stack Overflow question I got it from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-in-python which predates yours by 3 years. A lot could happen in 3 years so it was reasonable to expect that a function *did* exist but obviously there is no intention to add string.isNumeric() to python.

Comment: sounds like we won't need to wait too long, but its v3 ... https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric in v2.7 there is an "isnumeric" for unicode objects